# Azure disk encryption for Linux VM

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-virtual-machine

I've encrypted the data disk attached to Linux VM. Later I've decided to encrypt also OS disk, but nothings happened.
It is not supported to encrypt OS disk afterwards Data disk encryption has been enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Some distributions do not support encrypting the OS disk, link below takes you to the breakdown

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-disk-encryption-faq#which-virtual-machine-tiers-does-azure-disk-encryption-support